# Vaadin set component color to hex or int or rgb

Tags: java, vaadin

I am currently messing about with Vaadin.

I see that that I can change background color of e.g. button like so:

```
cButton.getStyle().set("background","red");
```

But if I want to set a specific color like this one: #EAB251. How can it be done?

This color could change depending on what the user chooses in an RGB-/HEX-/INT-color picker.

Comment: Have you tried using the hex value instead of red? What does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any valid CSS value for the property. So `cButton.getStyle().set("background", "#EAB251")` and `cButton.getStyle().set("background", "rgb(234, 178, 81)")` should work. In fact, the line of code you posted works because `red` is a CSS color name.

Comment: I hate that it was that easy... Thank you a lot. Is it possible to do it with a int as well? For example "-14188855". If not, I could just turn it into a hex-color, I suppose.

Comment: I don't think so. You can use any CSS color expression, though. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value for more information.